# Scroll in wx.Panel

Tags: wxpython, python-3.4

There is an object:

```
self.m_panelDraw = wx.Panel(self.panel, -1, size=(400, 150), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
```

I want to add a SVG document to this object:

```
svgStr = svg_code_generation()
cdc = wx.ClientDC(self.m_panelDraw)
dc = wx.GCDC(cdc)
odc = wx.DCOverlay(self.Overlay, cdc) # self.Overlay = wx.Overlay()
odc.Clear()

bmp = transformation_svg_to_bitmap(svgStr, 1)

if bmp is not None:
    dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)
```

Let there be a SVG document: width="1000" height="600". Size wx.Panel (400, 150). The result is:
[image]

It is evident that not all of the SVG document have been placed (it is logical).

Question: Can I somehow add scrolling to wx.Panel?

Comment: https://www.wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.scrolledpanel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend you check out wxPython's `ScolledPanel` widget or the `wx.ScrolledWindow` widget.

You might also find the documentation on `wx.Scrolled` helpful: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Scrolled.html